# Rails controller isn't getting specific params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, parameter-passing, wicked-gem

I'm trying to follow wicked tutorial for creating an object partially
( https://github.com/zombocom/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step )

The problem is, I am having trouble creating the object itself. I've tried with and without strong params, or even making the call out of the controller, but can get it passed. What am I doing wrong?

```
class ProspectsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :signup, :business_details, :user_details

  def show
    create_prospect if params[:prospect_id].nil?
    byebug # => prospect_id is no appearing =>  Not_found
    @prospect = Prospect.find(params[:prospect_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @prospect = Prospect.find(params[:prospect_id])
    params[:prospect][:status] = 'users_detailed' if step == steps.last
    @prospect.update_attributes(params[:prospect])
    render_wizard @prospect
  end

  def create_prospect
    @prospect = Prospect.create
    new_prospect_build_path(prospect_id: @prospect.id)
  end

  # def prospect_params
  #   params.require(:prospect).
  #     permit(:user_first_name, :user_last_name, :user_email, :dni, :plan, :empresa_name, :empresa_email,
  #        :empresa_phone, :empresa_address, :empresa_web, :empresa_category, :empresa_summary, :user_birthday,
  #      :user_phone, :user_address, :sex, :iban_code, :status, :prospect_id)
  # end
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :prospects, only: [:show, :update] do
    resources :build, controller: 'prospects'
  end
```

[image]

Comment: post output of `rake routes`

Comment: information updated

Comment: you're using same controller action for two routes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using same controller action for two routes:

```
GET /prospects/:prospect_id/build/:id => prospects#show

GET /prospects/:id => prospects#show
```

same with update.
If you will get to that controller by `GET prospect_path` you will not get `:prospect_id`, but `:id`.